# Updating state while in a JSZIP file

Tags: reactjs, jszip

I'm using the library JSZip to read a user-uploaded zip file and I want to load the contents of each file into the state.

Here's a toned-down version of reading the zip file:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const onUploadClick = () => {
  const load = (filename) => {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => {
        jzip.file(filename).async(`arraybuffer`).then(
          (content) => {
            return resolve(Array.from(new Uint8Array(content)));
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }

  jzip.loadAsync(file).then(
    (zip) => {
      zip.forEach(
        async (_, entry) => {
          const filename = entry[`name`];
          const buffer = await load(filename);
          const newFiles = [...files];
          newFiles.push(buffer);
          setFiles([...newFiles]);
      )
    }
  )
}
```

I then used `useEffect` to monitor the changes to the `files` state component:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    console.log(files)
  },
  [files]
);
```

But what I get out is just the following when trying to load a zip file with 3 files inside:

[image: output]

Instead, I am expecting something like

```
[Array(33), Array(33), Array(33)]
```

So it's reading each file correctly, converting to a `Uint8Array`, and adding it to the state, but the state is not retaining the previous files.

I also tried pushing just the filename into the `files` state component, and same error.

I am unsure why this is happening. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code below:

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const onUploadClick = () => {
  const load = (filename) => {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => {
        jzip.file(filename).async(`arraybuffer`).then(
          (content) => {
            return resolve(Array.from(new Uint8Array(content)));
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }

  jzip.loadAsync(file).then(
    (zip) => {
      const newFiles = [];
      zip.forEach(
        async (_, entry) => {
          const filename = entry[`name`];
          const buffer = await load(filename);
          newFiles.push(buffer);
       }
     )
     setFiles(newFiles);
  )
}
```

The state update `setFiles` was not finished yet before trying to add a new entry, therefore `files` was not updated yet when trying to add a 2nd one. Same for the third file: it pulled the current `files` array (which was still empty, because the state update before it had not finished) and pushed something new. That's why there was only ever one item in the list.